# Smooth scroll header with fixed position

Tags: jquery, html, css, smooth-scrolling

How to create smooth scroll when I change the position to fixed. I try to add the animation but it does not work. Better use jquery animation();

```js
$(window).scroll(function() {
  var sticky = $('.mobile-menu'),
    scroll = $(window).scrollTop();

  if (scroll >= 40) sticky.addClass('fixed');
  else sticky.removeClass('fixed');
});
```

```css
header {
  padding: 20px 40px;
  background: gray;
  width: 100%;
  -webkit-transition: position 10s;
  -moz-transition: position 10s;
  -ms-transition: position 10s;
  -o-transition: position 10s;
  transition: position 10s;
}
section {
  height: 150vh;
}
.fixed {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<header class="mobile-menu">Text here</header>
<section>Sugar plum muffin cookie pastry oat cake icing candy canes chocolate. Gummi bears chupa chups fruitcake dessert jelly. Muffin cookie ice cream soufflé pastry lollipop gingerbread sweet. Unerdwear.com bonbon candy marzipan bonbon gummies chocolate cake
  gummi bears powder. Unerdwear.com tart halvah chocolate cake dragée liquorice. Sugar plum chocolate bar pastry liquorice dragée jelly powder. Jelly tootsie roll applicake caramels. Marzipan candy tootsie roll donut. Gummies ice cream macaroon applicake.</section>
```

Comment: You can't transition position property.

Comment: If you are looking for a simple and effective way of implementing a sticky header I would suggest using Bootstrap. It is easy to get going and all the heavy lifting is already done for you. Follow the quick start https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/getting-started/introduction/#quick-start Add the class name "navbar-fixed-top" to your nav and that is all. From there you have a similar sticky nav with simple start up.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

You can use `@keyframes` to add some transition effects to the scroll.

```js
$(window).scroll(function() {
  var sticky = $('.mobile-menu'),
    scroll = $(window).scrollTop();
   
  if (scroll >= 40) { 
    sticky.addClass('fixed'); }
  else { 
   sticky.removeClass('fixed');

}
});
```

```css
header {
  padding: 20px 40px;
  background: gray;
  width: 100%;
  
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease;
  -moz-transition: position 10s;
  -ms-transition: position 10s;
  -o-transition: position 10s;
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
}
section {
  height: 150vh;
}


.fixed {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  animation: smoothScroll 1s forwards;
}
@keyframes smoothScroll {
 0% {
  transform: translateY(-40px);
 }
 100% {
  transform: translateY(0px);
 }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<header class="mobile-menu">Text here</header>
<section>Sugar plum muffin cookie pastry oat cake icing candy canes chocolate. Gummi bears chupa chups fruitcake dessert jelly. Muffin cookie ice cream soufflé pastry lollipop gingerbread sweet. Unerdwear.com bonbon candy marzipan bonbon gummies chocolate cake
  gummi bears powder. Unerdwear.com tart halvah chocolate cake dragée liquorice. Sugar plum chocolate bar pastry liquorice dragée jelly powder. Jelly tootsie roll applicake caramels. Marzipan candy tootsie roll donut. Gummies ice cream macaroon applicake.</section>
```

Comment: When we back it, It's wrired now.

Comment: How to gentle smoothScroll when the class will be removed?

Comment: but text doesnt move smo0th

Answer (score 2):

**EDITED based on comment.**

If you change `position` to `fixed` while scrolling, it will generate undesired jump behavior.

Your best bet would be to prevent positioning while scrolling, setting `fixed` after `40px` or from the start is pretty much the same, so I'd suggest you remove this part on your jQuery, and make your `header` `fixed` from the start:

```
//if (scroll >= 40) sticky.addClass('fixed');
//else sticky.removeClass('fixed');
```

Snippet below:

```js
$(window).scroll(function() {
  var sticky = $('.mobile-menu'),
    scroll = $(window).scrollTop();
});
```

```css
body {
  position: relative;
}
header {
  padding: 20px 40px;
  background: gray;
  width: 100%;
  -webkit-transition: position 10s;
  -moz-transition: position 10s;
  -ms-transition: position 10s;
  -o-transition: position 10s;
  transition: position 10s;
}
section {
  height: 150vh;
  position: relative;
  top: 60px;
}
.fixed {
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 1;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<header class="mobile-menu fixed">Text here</header>
<section>Sugar plum muffin cookie pastry oat cake icing candy canes chocolate. Gummi bears chupa chups fruitcake dessert jelly. Muffin cookie ice cream soufflé pastry lollipop gingerbread sweet. Unerdwear.com bonbon candy marzipan bonbon gummies chocolate cake
  gummi bears powder. Unerdwear.com tart halvah chocolate cake dragée liquorice. Sugar plum chocolate bar pastry liquorice dragée jelly powder. Jelly tootsie roll applicake caramels. Marzipan candy tootsie roll donut. Gummies ice cream macaroon applicake.</section>
```

Comment: I can not add the margin-top to section, because I have a lot of page with the different content.