# How can I animate a sticky navbar

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

My project has a sticky header after scrolling that uses this script:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  $(window).scroll(function () {
      //if you hard code, then use console
      //.log to determine when you want the 
      //nav bar to stick.  
      console.log($(window).scrollTop())
    if ($(window).scrollTop() > 385) {
      $('#nav').addClass('navbar-fixed');
    }
    if ($(window).scrollTop() < 386) {
      $('#nav').removeClass('navbar-fixed');
    }
  });
});
```

How can I animate this so that it looks better?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can also use [jQuery animations](https://api.jquery.com/category/effects/). as you are already using jQuery

Answer (score 4):

You can animate your fixed nav bar like this:

```
.navbar-fixed {
    animation: mymove 0.2s ease-in-out;

    @keyframes mymove {
      from {
        top: -20px;
      }
      to {
        top: 0px;
      }
    }
}
```

Move the nav bar element from -20px to 0px top. The animation lasts for .2s seconds.
Hope this help you :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use CSS and key frames to animate to the class added and removed.  Here below similar questions by using key frames for smooth scrolling 
[smooth scrolling sticky header](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41678751/smooth-scroll-header-with-fixed-position/41680823#41680823)